# Unable to cast bindingsource to datatable

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable, crystal-reports

I have the following code:

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt = CType(Me.DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)

        Dim cr As New Reporte_cotiza
        cr.SetDataSource(dt)

        Dim imprime As New Reporte
        imprime.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr
        imprime.ShowDialog()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
```

I want to print the content of a datagridview using Crystal Reports. But when I press my "Print" button I get the error:

> unable to cast object of type "System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource" to type "System.Data.DataTable"

I will appreciate any help

Comment: Apparently the datasource of your grid is a BindingSource object, not a DataTable.

Comment: If you didn't assign a `DataTable` to the `DataSource` of the grid in the first place then why would you expect to be able to get one back?  What is the type of the parameter of the `SetDataSource` method?  It may well be that you can simply cast the `DataSource` of the grid as that type and it will work whether it's a `DataTable` or `BindingSource`.  If you specifically need a `DataTable` then you would presumably get that from the `DataSource` of the `BindingSource`.